# Car making very very loud noise like a fan straining

Tags: engine

I drive a Toyota corolla 2015 car. When driving it suddenly made a loud noise that sounds like a metal grinder straining to cut a piece of metal. When start it it fine, but once I engage reverse and drive a little, the noise starts. What could be the problem?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information for someone to give a useful answer. Does the noise change pitch with changing engine RPM? Can you tell where in the engine the noise seems to be coming from? To begin troubleshooting, I'd recommend pulling over as soon as the noise starts and checking under the hood. Since you mention it sounds like the fan straining, the fan bearing might be wearing out. Alternatively, if it's a repetitive, high pitched noise, it could be the serpentine belt slipping or a misaligned pulley. Take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/AEUe6uKxTv8) as a start.